# Power BI to navigate searchable database

Tags: arrays, database, web-scraping, automation, powerbi

I'm kinda new to Power BI but  Im really interested from what ive seen online for capturing data within databases. I thought I would give it a go myself to collect data for chemicals of interest and it worked great where the URL contains an obvious dataset.

The second dataset requires more navigation and I this is a barrier. For example you have to search for a keyword and then this will return a bunch of matching items (one if your specific enough) which you then have to click to get the data on the page.

Does anyone familiar with power BI know if it can be used to actually navigate a searchable database to get to the data?

For example If I wanted to get  info from https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals. Is it possible to have a list of chemicals e.g. Formaldehyde or Hydrochloric Acid, search these names in the database, possibly click on tabs to get to the relevant page and then return found values in a table?

Any advice on this problem would be appreciated. So far I can only see that PowerBI is able to find data thats kind of obviously presented on the page. Is it possible to navigate between webpages in this way? I have hundred of chemicals to research and its very repetitive.